# Loop twice on reducer utterable

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am implementing two phase matrix multiplication. Following piece is for reducer of first phase. Key is row index from left file and column index from right file. 
I expect output count to map and reducer to be same. But it looks like inner loop increments same iterator as that of outer loop and thus number of reducer output is equal to number of keys.

Code piece :

```
@Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            for (Text outer : values) {
                String [] outerLine = outer.toString().split("\t");
                //int outerIndex = 0;
                //outerIndex = outerLine[0].equalsIgnoreCase(leftFilePattern) ? outerIndex : 1;
                if(outerLine[0].equalsIgnoreCase(rightFilePattern))
                    continue;
                double outerValue = Double.parseDouble(outerLine[2]);
                for (Text inner : values) {
                    String [] innerLine = inner.toString().split("\t");
                    if(innerLine[0].equalsIgnoreCase(leftFilePattern))
                        continue;
                    context.write(new Text(key.toString() + "-" + innerLine[1]), 
                                new DoubleWritable(outerValue * Double.parseDouble(innerLine[2])));
                }
            }
```

But when i have simple java application like following :

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(10, 15);
        Iterable<Integer> it = l;
        for (Integer in : it) {
            for (Integer out : it) {
                System.out.println(in + " " + out);
            }
        }
```

here number of output is 4. If inner loop works same as in case of reducer, output count should have been 1 i.e. (10 15).

Can some one explain this behavior.

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible way of implementing `Iterable` that could cause that effect.

The intent seems to be that each `iterator()` call should return its own `Iterator` instance. The `Iterable` classes in `java.util`, including the private `List` class used by `Arrays.asList()`, all do so. That behavior is needed for nested foreach on the same `Iterable`, and the stated purpose of `Iterable` is foreach support.

I cannot find anything in the `Iterable` API document that directly requires that behavior.

Obviously, if the same object is used as result of two `iterator()` calls, nested foreach statements on the same `Iterable` will fail the way you describe.

=========================================================

If this is what is happening, my best suggestion is to do an initial pass over `values` copying each Text reference to a well-behaved `List<Text>` such as an `ArrayList`. You can safely do your nested loop over its elements.

Comment: yeh different implementation are free to implement it differently but then they should use different name. Using same name for different behavior makes it difficult to work with ...

Comment: @VishalKumar The Iterator interface API document really should have specified that each iterator() call returns a distinct object.